# Can I enter Romania from Dubai with a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, dubai, romania

Would I be able to enter Romania on a Schengen visa if I'm staying less than 5 days? Basically I would be doing Dubai-Romania-Dubai.

Comment: No, because Romania is not in the Schengen Area

Comment: What passport are you on?

Comment: Romania, like Bulgaria, are both fighting to get into Schengen. Part of this has been to bring their own visa rules into line with Schengen rules, to the point that there are special concessions that people with Schengen visas qualify for.

Comment: Here is the link to the Ministry of Foreign Affairs detailing romanian visa regime : http://mae.ro/en/node/2040

Comment: Pretty exact duplicate of [Travelling to Romania on a short stay Schengen visa issued by France?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22511/travelling-to-romania-on-a-short-stay-schengen-visa-issued-by-france)

Comment: @SantaC. The linked question is older and now closed as a dupe of this one, so this one shouldn't be closed as duplicate.

Comment: So this doesn't work. Same story Dubai Bucharest Athens. They refused entry

Comment: @Trans When was that? What type of Schengen visa did you have? What was your itinerary? The rules have changed since this question and answer were written but genuine transit should in any case still be possible (merely coming to Romania without going to the Schengen area with only a single-entry Schengen visa might not).

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can! This is how to do:

1. You have to have a valid Schengen Visa
2. You are eligible to stay up to 5 days in Romania
3. You have to show the immigration that your next destination is a Schengen Country (ex: Greece, France, etc.) and in this case your trip should be Dubai - Romania - Athens (for transit) - Dubai

This type of visa is called a transit Visa which is valid only for 5 days in Romania as long as you travel to a Schengen country afterwards.

For the details of the policy, see the [Romania Ministry of Foreign Affairs website](http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040).

Comment: can you provide a source to confirm this information?

Comment: I don't have a reference either but this sounds very familiar from when [an Indonesian friend wanted to come meet me in Romania](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6451/is-it-easier-cheaper-for-an-indonesian-with-uk-residency-to-obtain-a-tourist-vis) and we were checking all these rules about a year ago.

Comment: These conditions are no longer current after July 2014. The link in this answer describes a more recent policy.

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_in_the_European_Union):

> A Schengen visa is only valid for the Schengen Area. For individuals
>   who require a visa for Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus and/or Romania, a
>   separate Bulgarian/Croatian/Cypriot/Romanian visa has to be obtained.
>   Note that holders of a Schengen visa can enter Bulgaria and Croatia
>   for up to 90 days in a 180 day period and/or transit through Romania
>   for up to 5 days during the validity of their Schengen visa without
>   having to apply for Bulgarian, Croatian and/or Romanian visas.

Comment: This description is no longer current since July 2014.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a Schengen Visa with 2 or multiple entries then you can get into Romania even if you don't want to go a Schengen State afterwards. This kind of stay is limited to only 90 days.

Here is the source : http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040

In case you hold passport of any of the countries listed in here (http://www.mae.ro/sites/default/files/file/pdf/formulare-consulare/Vize/2014.06.09_annex_2_en_conf_reg_509-2014.pdf) then you don't need any kind of visa to travel to Romania.
ANSWER

I know this answer already exists, but I wanted to add sources for reference and because I cannot comment on previous answers because of reputation so I added another answer

Comment: Add the  relevant content of your cited links in the answer. Links are prone to 404- oblivion. ;)